# How to loop over array to display in HTML table

Tags: javascript

I have some JSON data which is an array of objects. Inside the objects there's some string properties but also array properties.

I'm trying to display the array properties stacked with each array index result underneath other as opposed to side by side.

I'm not sure how to do this inside a table element.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GTP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="players"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gtp.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
// Fetch players
function fetchPlayers(api) {
    fetch(api)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(players => {
            displayPlayers(players);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}

fetchPlayers('players.json');

// Display players
const displayPlayers = (players) => {
    // Players HTML container
    let playersElement = document.getElementById('players');
    let playersContent = '';

    playersContent += '<ul>';

    const playersList = players.players;

    const player = playersList[Math.floor(Math.random() * playersList.length)];

    console.log(player);

    const playerDetails = () => {
        playersContent += '<tr>';

        playersContent += `<td>${player.years}</td>`;
        playersContent += `<td>${player.teams}</td>`;
        playersContent += `<td>${player.apps}</td>`;
        playersContent += `<td>${player.gls}</td>`;

        playersContent += '</tr>';
    }

    playersContent += `<table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Years</th>
                                                <th>Team</th>
                                                <th>Apps</th>
                                                <th>(Gls)</th>
                                            </tr>`
                                                playerDetails();
                                        `</table>`;

    playersContent += '</ul>';

    playersElement.innerHTML = playersContent;
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Michael Owen",
            "position": "Striker",
            "years": ["1996-2004", "2004-2005", "2005-2009", "2009-2012", "2012-2013"],
            "teams": ["Liverpool", "Real Madrid", "Newcastle United", "Manchester United", "Stoke City"],
            "apps": ["216", "36", "71", "31", "8"],
            "gls": ["118", "13", "26", "5", "1"]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Robbie Savage",
            "position": "Midfielder",
            "years": ["1993-1994", "1994-1997", "1997-2002", "2002-2005", "2005-2008"],
            "teams": ["Manchester United", "Crewe Alexandre", "Leicester City", "Birmingham City", "Blackburn Rovers", "Derby Country", "Brighton & Hove Albion (loan)"],
            "apps": ["0", "77", "172", "82", "76", "124", "6"],
            "gls": ["0", "10", "8", "11", "1", "7", "0"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: One way to find out what you have to do is, to create your expected table output manually at first. According my own experience in the past, it was a helpful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an unordered list inside the table cell to display them one below other.

```
`<td><ul>${player.years.map(year => `<li>${year}</li>`).join("")}</ul></td>`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @nithin's answer, you need to iterate through array instead of just displaying it directly. If you don't want to use `<li>` tag (as it would add pointers) you can do it old and simple way like this,

instead of line

```
playersContent += `<td>${player.years}</td>`;
```

use it like,

```
for(var i=0;i<player.years.length;i++){
        if(i==0)
            playersContent += player.years[i];
        else
           playersContent += `<br/>`+player.years[i];
        }
```